# C- How to find and change a single particular character in a string

Tags: c

I'm trying to make something that changes only one character in a string. As an example.

```
char str[10];
fgets(str,10,stdin); //input hello
// do something to change 'hello to he1lo'
```

All I can found is some functions change all of same letters.

Comment: you can access the corresponding index then modify it. In the above example you can modify by str[2] = '1';

Comment: Yeah, but its based on users input, program shouldn't decide the string

Comment: You can search for a letter you want to replace, replace it and exit from a function.

Comment: I know but if you do that you will change all same letters, i want to change only one

Comment: My solution below must solve your problem. I hope I have understood your question correctly :-)

Comment: So you want to modify only the first occurrence of that character?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can modify by searching through a string then replace it with new char.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int replace(char *str,const char old_char,const char new_char,const int replace_char_count) {

    int count_replaced_chars = 0;
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0';i++) {
        if(str[i] == old_char) {
            str[i] = new_char;
            count_replaced_chars++;
            if(count_replaced_chars == replace_char_count)
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    char str[10];
    char new_char = '1';
    char old_char = 'l';
    int replace_char_count = 0;

    printf("Enter the string in which chars to be replaced\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(str,10,stdin); //input hello

    printf("Enter how many chars to replaced\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d",&replace_char_count);


    if(!replace(str,old_char,new_char,replace_char_count))
        printf("Successfully %d number of replaced char\n",replace_char_count);
    else
        printf("char not found\n");

    printf("%s\n",str);

}
```

Comment: Yes this is it, Just curious what if input is helllo how can i make it he11lo?

Comment: then can you accept the answer? . For modifying multiple(eg: 2) letters. In the replace function you can count how many letters you have replaced and exit from the function when the count is 2.

Comment: I would if user could pick how many times it would change.

Comment: You can get a input from a user how many letters he/she wants to modify and pass that value to function as a parameter.

Comment: Can you show where i should modify i have been messing with a code for 5 hours. My brain is going to explode :(

Comment: My update to the answer should help you for any number of characters you want replace. Don't forget to upvote the answer.

Comment: Oh i get it now lol, thanks

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to output all of possible changes? I tried it about 30 mins but nothing.